# TDD/ testing with streams in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, testing, stream, tdd

I've been trying to find a reasonable way to test code that uses streams. Has anyone found a reasonable way/ framework to help testing code that uses streams in nodejs?

For example:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

module.exports = function (url, path, callback) {
  request(url)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
    .on('finish', function () {
      callback();
    });
};
```

My current way of testing this type of code either involves simplifying the code with streams so much that I can abstract it out to a non-tested chunk of code or by writing something like this:

```
var rewire = require('rewire'),
    download = rewire('../lib/download'),
    stream = require('stream'),
    util = require('util');

describe('download', function () {
  it('should download a url', function (done) {
    var fakeRequest, fakeFs, FakeStream;

    FakeStream = function () {
      stream.Writable.call(this);
    };

    util.inherits(FakeStream, stream.Writable);

    FakeStream.prototype._write = function (data, encoding, cb) {
      expect(data.toString()).toEqual("hello world")
      cb();
    };

    fakeRequest = function (url) {
      var output = new stream.Readable();

      output.push("hello world");
      output.push(null);

      expect(url).toEqual('http://hello');

      return output;
    };

    fakeFs = {
      createWriteStream: function (path) {
        expect(path).toEqual('hello.txt');
        return new FakeStream();
      }
    };

    download.__set__('fs', fakeFs);
    download.__set__('request', fakeRequest);

    download('http://hello', 'hello.txt', function () {
      done();
    });

  });
});
```

Has anyone come up with more elegant ways of testing streams?

Answer (score 17):

Made streamtest for that purpose. It not only make streams tests cleaner but also allows to test V1 and V2 streams https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamtest

Comment: Thank you for the lib. It was exactly what i needed and it works great.

Comment: You made my day! Thanks for this @nfroidure

Answer (score 7):

I've also been using [memorystream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystream), but then putting my assertions into the `finish` event. That way it looks more like a real use of the stream being tested:

```
require('chai').should();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var MemoryStream = require('memorystream');
var memStream = MemoryStream.createWriteStream();

/**
 * This is the Transform that we want to test:
 */

var Parser = require('../lib/parser');
var parser = new Parser();

describe('Parser', function(){
  it('something', function(done){
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'something.txt'))
      .pipe(parser)
      .pipe(memStream)
      .on('finish', function() {

        /**
         * Check that our parser has created the right output:
         */

        memStream
          .toString()
          .should.eql('something');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Checking objects can be done like this:

```
var memStream = MemoryStream.createWriteStream(null, {objectMode: true});
.
.
.
      .on('finish', function() {
        memStream
          .queue[0]
          .should.eql({ some: 'thing' });
        done();
      });
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 6):

Read the Stream into memory and compare it with the expected Buffer.

```
it('should output a valid Stream', (done) => {
  const stream = getStreamToTest();
  const expectedBuffer = Buffer.from(...);
  let bytes = new Buffer('');

  stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    bytes = Buffer.concat([bytes, chunk]);
  });

  stream.on('end', () => {
    try {
      expect(bytes).to.deep.equal(expectedBuffer);
      done();
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel you pain.

I don't know any framework to help out testing with streams, but if take a look [here](https://github.com/markuz-gj/super-stream.through/tree/master/spec),
where I'm developing a stream library, you can see how I approach this problem.

here is a idea of what I'm doing.

```
var chai = require("chai")
, sinon = require("sinon")
, chai.use(require("sinon-chai"))
, expect = chai.expect
, through2 = require('through2')
;

chai.config.showDiff = false

function spy (stream) {
  var agent, fn
  ;
  if (spy.free.length === 0) {
    agent = sinon.spy();
  } else {
    agent = spy.free.pop();
    agent.reset();
  }
  spy.used.push(agent);
  fn = stream._transform;
  stream.spy = agent;
  stream._transform =  function(c) {
    agent(c);
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  stream._transform = transform;
  return agent;
};

spy.free = [];
spy.used = [];


describe('basic through2 stream', function(){

  beforeEach(function(){
    this.streamA = through2()
    this.StreamB = through2.obj()
    // other kind of streams...

    spy(this.streamA)
    spy(this.StreamB)

  })

  afterEach(function(){
    spy.used.map(function(agent){
      spy.free.push(spy.used.pop())
    })
  })

  it("must call transform with the data", function(){
    var ctx = this
    , dataA = new Buffer('some data')
    , dataB = 'some data'
    ;

    this.streamA.pipe(through2(function(chunk, enc, next){
      expect(ctx.streamA.spy).to.have.been.calledOnce.and.calledWidth(dataA)
    }))

    this.streamB.pipe(through2(function(chunk, enc, next){
      expect(ctx.streamB.spy).to.have.been.calledOnce.and.calledWidth(dataB)
    }))

    this.streamA.write(dataA)
    this.streamB.write(dataB)

  })

})
```

Note that my spy function wraps the `_transform` method and call my spy and call the original  `_transform`

Also, The `afterEach` function is recycling the spies, because you can end up creating hundreds of them.

The problem gets hard is when you want to test async code. Then promises your best friend. The link I gave above have some sample that.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this, and it's quite old, but https://github.com/dominictarr/stream-spec might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can test streams using [MemoryStream](https://github.com/JSBizon/node-memorystream) and [sinon](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS) by using spies. Here is how I tested some of my code.

```
describe('some spec', function() {
    it('some test', function(done) {
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        var spyCB = sinon.spy();

        outputStream.on('data', spyCB);

        doSomething(param, param2, outputStream, function() {
            sinon.assert.calledWith(spyCB, 'blah');

            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way I have found is to use events

```
const byline = require('byline');
const fs = require('fs');

it('should process all lines in file', function(done){
   //arrange
   let lines = 0;
   //file with 1000 lines
   let reader = fs.readFileStream('./input.txt');
   let writer = fs.writeFileStream('./output.txt');
   //act
   reader.pipe(byline).pipe(writer);
   byline.on('line', function() {
     lines++;
   });
   //assert
   writer.on('close', function() {
     expect(lines).to.equal(1000);
     done();
   });
});
```

by passing done as a callback, mocha waits until it is called before moving on.